# Convert XML from one format to another

Tags: sql-server, xml, t-sql, xpath, xquery

I have this below xml data which is stored in a table.

**The XML Structure I have**

```
<Response>
    <Question ID="1">
        <Value ID="1">I want a completely natural childbirth - no medical interventions for me</Value>
        <Value ID="2">no medical interventions for me</Value>
    </Question>
</Response>
```

I need to convert this XML to a slightly different format, like the below one.

**The XML Structure I need**

```
<Response>
    <Question ID="1">
        <SelectedChoices>
            <Choice>
                <ID>1</ID>
            </Choice>
            <Choice>
                <ID>2</ID>
            </Choice>
        </SelectedChoices>
    </Question>
</Response>
```

Here the "Value" is changed to "Choice" and "ID" attribute of "Value" element is changed to an element.

I know this can be done in [other ways](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/mrorke/2005/06/28/performing-xslt-transforms-on-xml-data-stored-in-sql-server-2005/), like using an XSLT. But it will be much more helpful if can accomplish with SQL itself.

Can someone help me to convert this using SQL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this variable to test the statements

```
DECLARE @xml XML=
N'<Response>
    <Question ID="1">
        <Value ID="1">I want a completely natural childbirth - no medical interventions for me</Value>
        <Value ID="2">no medical interventions for me</Value>
    </Question>
</Response>';
```

### This can be done with [`FLWOR-XQuery`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190945.aspx):

The query will re-build the XML out of itself... Very similar to `XSLT`...

```
SELECT @xml.query(
N'
<Response>
{
for $q in /Response/Question
    return 
    <Question ID="{$q/@ID}">
    <SelectedChoices>
    {
    for $v in $q/Value
        return <Choice><ID>{string($v/@ID)}</ID></Choice>
    }
    </SelectedChoices>
    </Question>
}
</Response>
'
);
```

### Another approach: Shredding and re-build

You'd reach the same with this, but I'd prefere the first...

```
WITH Shredded AS
(
    SELECT q.value('@ID','int') AS qID
          ,v.value('@ID','int') AS vID
    FROM @xml.nodes('/Response/Question') AS A(q)
    OUTER APPLY q.nodes('Value') AS B(v)
)
SELECT t1.qID AS [@ID]
      ,(
        SELECT t2.vID AS ID
        FROM Shredded AS t2
        WHERE t1.qID=t2.qID
        FOR XML PATH('Choice'),ROOT('SelectedChoices'),TYPE
       ) AS [node()]
FROM Shredded AS t1
GROUP BY t1.qID
FOR XML PATH('Question'),ROOT('Response')
```